# Adding switch /ini=nul to WinSCP command-line does not work

Tags: command-line, sftp, winscp

I am trying to write an automated script to upload a file to sftp using WinSCP. 
The initial script below works with no error

```
C:\Users\anh le>"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /command "open sftp://username:password@sftphost/" "cd /ADHOC" "put ""C:\Temp\ldg_pnv.csv""" "close" "exit"
```

But when I added the `/ini=nul` switch, the upload didn't work and also didn't return any error.
Does anyone has any idea why adding the switch, which is recommended by the way, caused this?

```
C:\Users\anh le>"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /ini=nul /command "open sftp://username:password@sftphost/" "cd /ADHOC" "put ""C:\Temp\ldg_pnv.csv""" "close" "exit"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but indeed your command with `/ini=nul` cannot work. You are connecting to an SSH (SFTP) server and that requires a [verification of the server's host key](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey#automation). Your script does not do that and as you use `/ini=nul`, WinSCP won't use (possibly) cached hostkey from your WinSCP GUI configuration.

---

Though, I'm sure WinSCP does *"return error"*. You just cannot see the error printed because, you do not enable logging ([`/log` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging)), nor you use console interface ([`winscp.com`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables) or [`/console`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting)).

---

A full command can be like this:

```
C:\Users\anh le>"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /log=C:\some\path\winscp.log /ini=nul /command "open sftp://username:password@sftphost/ -hostkey=""server_host_key""" "cd /ADHOC" "put ""C:\Temp\ldg_pnv.csv""" "close" "exit"
```

WinSCP GUI can [generate a full command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) like this for you, including the `-hostkey` switch.